# python web scraping google news

Tags: python, web-scraping

i am trying to write a script for web scraping the google news web site and the code i wrote is not showing any result. I dont know why.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def scrapeGoogleNews():
RESULT = []
base_url = "https://news.google.com"
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"}

response = requests.get(base_url, headers=headers)
assert response.status_code == 200

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all("div", class_="xrnccd")

for result in results:
    title = result.find("h3", class_="ipQwMb").text
    description = result.find("div", class_="s3v9rd").text
    news_url = "https://news.google.com" + result.find("a", class_="VDXfz").get("href")
    RESULT.append([title, description, news_url])

return RESULT

# Example usage:
news_articles = scrapeGoogleNews()
for article in news_articles:
print("Title:", article[0])
print("Description:", article[1])
print("URL:", article[2])
print()
```

this is the code i wrote

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A better method I would recommend is instead of searching for a specific class try detecting the elements with an ID or something similar. Because of its uniqueness it can return better results. Also consider instead of manually retrieving the title, description, URL etc. using a library like [newspaper3k](https://newspaper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score -1):

Ultimately I think this is simply because there are no valid results in the HTML you are retrieving.

Focus on this line:

```py
results = soup.find_all("div", class_="xrnccd")
```

This is searching for all `div` tags with a `class` of `xrnccd`, for example `<div class="xrnccd">`. When I ran this, the HTML that was returned did not contain any tags that matched this criteria.

I'm not sure what the intention is with this code, but I would suggest that when you retrieve the HTML from the website, write the HTML to a file. This will allow you to search through the HTML and see what kind of data you're working with. For example:

```py
base_url = "https://news.google.com"
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36"}

response = requests.get(base_url, headers=headers)
assert response.status_code == 200

with open("data.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(response.text)
```

There's no need to write to a file every time you run the code, but it is a useful thing to do at least once while debugging these kinds of problems.